# Is it true that every closed set is a countable intersection of open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Motivation:

We know that every open set is a countable union of open intervals with rational endpoints and that every open interval is a countable union of closed intervals. Hence every open set is a countable union of closed intervals. It follows by De Morgan's laws that every closed set is a countable intersection of open sets.

I would like to ask if we can prove a stronger result that

> every closed set is a countable intersection of open intervals.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is *no*, since an intersection of intervals is also an interval. Thus, if a closed set were to be a countable intersection of open intervals, it would have to be a closed *interval*, but there are closed sets that are not intervals.

For example (as @AlbertoTakase mentions in the comments below), consider the set $\{0\} \cup \{1\}$. This is a closed set since finite subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are closed, but it is clearly not a closed interval. Hence, it cannot be written as a countable intersection of open intervals.

Comment: (to add an example) Consider $\{0\}\cup\{1\}$ which is closed but not an interval.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase Yes, but that is not a countable intersection of open intervals.

Comment: I only wanted to give an example of the last remark in your answer.

Comment: Your answer is great!

Comment: That's not necessarily true for *countable* intersections.  Any set of isolated points (which is necessarily countable) is a countable intersection of open intervals.  For example, $\{0\} = \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N} (-2^{-n}, 2^{-n})$.

Comment: @RobertShore Not any set of isolated points can be a countable intersection of open intervals, only singletons. And singletons are also (trivially) closed intervals.

Comment: @LeAnhDung Glad to be of help :)

Comment: @AlbertoTakase Ah, I see. I'll pull your example up into the answer for clarity :)